# Java Set.containsAll returns true for empty list

Tags: java, collections, set

The `containsAll` method in the `AbstractCollection` class is implemented as below:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c)
        if (!contains(e))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't check for empty c and still returns `true` for the below testcase:

```
@Test
public void testContainsAllOfHashSet() {
    List<String> reasons = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<String> allReasons = new HashSet<>();
    allReasons.add("Java");
    Assert.assertFalse(allReasons.containsAll(reasons));
}
```

The above test is failing as `containsAll` is returning `true` for empty reasons. `allreasons` contains at least one element and definitely no empty elements are there. Therefore, the above test case should pass. Let me know if my understanding here is wrong.

Comment: Why do you expect this to return false? The result as current is logically correct: you're asking if the list contains all items of a list, and the answer to that is: yes, it contains all those items (the fact that the list is empty does not make that assertion false).

Comment: To put it another way: `x.containsAll(y)` should only return *false* if there's an element in `y` which isn't in `x`. Which element do you believe meets that condition in `allReasons.contains(reasons)`?

Comment: Or phrased differently, you're asking if for all items in `reasons`, is each item contained in `allReasons`, and that assertion is true if `reasons` is empty. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set

Comment: You may also want to read up on [power sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set); the empty set is a subset of a non-empty set.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, those wiki pages really helped.

Comment: Also known as [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.containsAll(y)`  returns `true` if `x` contains all the elements in `y`, which in this case, is a vacuous truth.

It's easier to understand if you rephrase the definition in negative terms - `x.containsAll(y)` returns `true` if `y` has no element that is not contained in `x`. If `y` is empty it has no elements at all, and specifically cannot have any element that isn't contained in `x`.

In short, in your case `allReasons.containsAll(reasons)` should return `true`, and your current assertion is wrong.

Comment: "the assertion is wrong" might be better understandable as "your assertion is wrong".